# Any way to get type hints to work for both 2.7/3.6 in VS code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'd like to use type hints in a few places. This syntax works with VS code, but isn't compatible with 2.7:

```
def foo(a: str, b: int) -> str:
    pass
```

From what I can tell, the following is the suggested way of using hints, but VS code doesn't recognize it:

```
def foo(a, b):
    # type: (str, int) -> str
    pass
```

The following works, though i'd hate to have to do it this way:

```
def foo(a, b):
    a = a  # type: str
    b = b  # type: int
    pass
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: My suggestions would be not to bother with Python 2.7. From what I can tell, probably VS Code is more focused on Python 3. Maybe try another editor, I guess PyCharm has better Python 2 support. And agreed, that mix of variable annotation to do function annotation looks ugly.

Comment: Type hints weren't introduced into Python until version 3.5 and is incompatible with Python 2. Like many Python 3 enhancements, it's syntactically incompatible with older versions of the language. Any workarounds to support both kinds of Python syntax should be provided by the creators of the VS IDE (for example. it could recognize specially formatted docstrings). Maybe you need a more Python-friendly IDE...

Comment: It appears that the second way, which you don't like but you say works with VS, is the suggested method to do it according [PEP 484 -- Type Hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) (in [this section](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#type-comments)). Perhaps you can make an editor macro (or something similar) that transforms a comment written the way you like into one or more in the needed format.

Comment: I just tested and the second option from my post does work in PyCharm. I was just hoping there was another way to do type hints that I was unfamiliar with that does work in VS code.

Comment: There's a module called _Type Hints for Python_ that might help, It's in pypi [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/typing).